# Mongoose Subdocuments Throwing Required Validation

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, subdocument

This is my schema

```
// grab the things we need
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var UserSchema = require('./user');

var inviteeSchema = new Schema({
  email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
  phone: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
});

// create a schema
var sessionSchema = new Schema({
  createdby: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
  invitees: [inviteeSchema],
  created_at: Date,
  updated_at: Date
});

// on every save, add the date
sessionSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
  // get the current date
  var currentDate = new Date();

  // change the updated_at field to current date
  this.updated_at = currentDate;

  // if created_at doesn't exist, add to that field
  if (!this.created_at)
    this.created_at = currentDate;

  next();
});

// the schema is useless so far
// we need to create a model using it
var Session = mongoose.model('Session', sessionSchema);

// make this available to our users in our Node applications
module.exports = Session;
```

And now, I'm doing the save as

```
router.post('/', function(req, res) {
  var session = new Session();

  //res.send(req.body);

  session.createdby = req.body.createdby;
  session.invitees.push({invitees: req.body.invitees});

  session.save(function(err) {
    if(err) res.send(err);
    res.json({status: 'Success'});
  });
});
```

Via Postman, I'm passing the createdby and invitees JSON as

```
[{"email": "1","phone": "1"},{"email": "2","phone": "2"}]
```

But, I'm always getting required error for phone and email.

I tried various solutions from stackoverflow, but nothing worked. I also tried passing single value as `{"email": "1","phone": "1"}` but it throws error too.

I even tried modifying my schema as below, but I still get validation error.

```
var sessionSchema = new Schema({
  createdby: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
  invitees: [{
    email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    phone: { type: String, required: true, unique: true }
  }],
  created_at: Date,
  updated_at: Date
});
```

Can anyone help me pointing out what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, finally after trying a lot, I found the solution. There was nothing wrong in my code. The problem was in Postman.

```
router.post('/', function(req, res) {
  var session = new Session(req.body);

  session.save(function(err) {
    if(err) res.send(err);
    res.json({status: 'Success'});
  });
});
```

When I was passing `[{"email": "1","phone": "1"},{"email": "2","phone": "2"}]` via Postman, it was getting converted into string as I had choose xxx-form-urlencoded. I needed to choose raw and application/json and then send the same string which worked fine.

So it was problem in the testing end.